# Graph drawing of gates and ports

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes} 
\usegdlibrary{layered,trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[layered layout,nodes={rectangle,fill=yellow,draw,}]{
{X, 7} % Inputs
->I/"\mbox{\quad}"[circle,fill=red]  % Input port
--F/$\sum$[fill=cyan!20,minimum width=3em,minimum height=1em]    % Function at the gate 
--O/$\bot$[circle,fill=green!30,
% regardless at=(r.north) this option does not work
]    % Output port%
};
[![\end{tikzpicture}][1]][1]
\end{document}
```

Whose output is

[image]

What I tried to do here is to create a meta-node out of nodes I, F, and O, which is similar to electronic gate. I is the input port, to which all input goes. F is the function computed at the node, and O is the output
node.

I tried defining I and O as nodes outside the `\graph` command so that their placement would be relative to F. The drawback is that the arrows
generated by the layout algorithm, are conect F, rather than I and O.

As shown in the MWE, I tried using `regardless at` key. But node placement was wrong.

In any particular case, it is of possible to `nudge` I and O towards F, but is it possible to nudge correctly for all possible layouts?

Is there a way to bring I and F closely together, so that they behave as one for graph drawing?

**EDIT**
To elaborate, I guess what I try to do is apply graph drawing to the
placement of arithmetical gates (similar to gates of electrical circuits).
Think of this drawing,

[image]

and imagine being able to the graph drawing libraries for placing the gates.

As I explained above, the challenge is in realizing the port functionality.

Comment: The circuits work because the input and output ports are defined for the shape (anchors in1, in2 and out).  If you don't want to define your own shapes, you can locate points relative to the existing anchors using the calc package.